# webdav exchange 2003 440

Tags: php, exchange-server, webdav

I'm trying to connect to a exchange 2003 server, and read the mails. The server has form based auth.

It all works fine on the login POST I get the two cookies, but when I try the second request the server sends a 440 status code.

I have included the request/respond serie (Server, pass, username and domain has been replased ), hope that anyone can see where I'm making a mistake.

```
**** REQUEST ******
>[url] => https://<SERVER>/exchweb/bin/auth/owaauth.dll
>[request_header] => POST /exchweb/bin/auth/owaauth.dll HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.83 Safari/537.1)
>   Accept: */*
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip
>   Cookie: cadata="2CurvKH0Qt2fgnqjSl4/bOTmdobQWv581GKUu5IxzspI+BN525+gHJdhkX8hmWWkLK9KdGWNd5Jd9Fz9/"; sessionid=8d0f4db8-0f3e-4b6d-90d1-bec8cff4fe5f
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Host: <CALLING SERVER>
>   Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
>   Content-Length: 152
>   destination=https%3A%2F%2F<SERVER>%2Fexchange%2F<USER>%2F&username=<DOMAIN>%5C<USER>&password=<PASSWORD>&SubmitCreds=Log+On&forcedownlevel=1&trusted=1



*** RESPONSE ****
<   string(421) "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
<   Content-Length: 0
<   Location: https://<SERVER/exchange/<USER>/
<   Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
<   MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
<   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
<   Set-Cookie: sessionid=3456b6f5-abd1-4bf9-8da3-539900f7f10d; path=/
<   Set-Cookie: cadata="17DhqZvs6837xRRMiNH2lBcCzo/AnK8Qbqj1mH791xfgUqy+TpnB201UvxcD9IePzaYLkZQfpjR2nOW3D"; HttpOnly; secure; path=/
<   Date: Wed, 05 Sep 2012 07:53:12 GMT


*** REQUEST ***
>   [url] => https://<SERVER>/exchange/<USER>/Indbakke
>   [request_header] => SEARCH /exchange/<USER>/Indbakke HTTP/1.0
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.83 Safari/537.1
>   Cookie: cadata="17DhqZvs6837xRRMiNH2lBcCzo/AnK8Qbqj1mH791xfgUqy+TpnB201UvxcD9IePzaYLkZQfpjR2nOW3D"; sessionid=3456b6f5-abd1-4bf9-8da3-539900f7f10d
>   Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
>   Accept-Language: da-DK,da;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>   Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Host: <CALLING SERVER>
>   Depth: 0
>   Translate: f
>   Content-type: application/xml;
>   Content-Length: 297

>   <?xml version="1.0"?><a:searchrequest xmlns:a="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/security/"> 
>      <a:sql> 
>          SELECT "DAV:displayname" 
>          ,"urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" 
>          FROM "https://<SERVER>/exchange/USER/Indbakke/" 
>      </a:sql> 
>   </a:searchrequest> 


*** RESPONSE ***
<   HTTP/1.1 440 Login Timeout
<   Set-Cookie: sessionid=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
<   Set-Cookie: cadata=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
<   Content-Type: text/html
<   Connection: close
<   Content-Length: 43
```

Answer (score 1):

"440 Login Timeout"
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941201

Your login details have expired and you need to login again. This is a OWA thing.